# Cake php login says invalid username and password even when they are correct

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp, authentication

I am trying to implement the login system from the Cake php blog tutorial into my own system but cannot seem to get it working. All attempts made to login are met with the error I set in UserController->login().

Heres some of my code, I can post more if needed.

UsersController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow(['add','logout']);
    }

    public function login() 
    {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if($user){
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again.'));
    }
}
```

AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Projects',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'edit', 'display']);
    }
}
```

login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please enter your username and password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

User.php

```
class User extends Entity
{

    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }

}
```

UsersTable.php

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('username');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Projects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('TicketsComments', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Projects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'project_id',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_users'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tickets', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'ticket_id',
            'joinTable' => 'tickets_users'
        ]);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('username', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is reuired.')
            ->add('username', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

        $validator
            ->email('email')
            ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('email')
            ->add('email', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required.');

        $validator
            ->notEmpty('role', 'A role is required.')
            ->add('role', 'inList', [
                'rule' => ['inList',['Admin', 'User']],
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role.'
            ]);

        return $validator;
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
        $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

I am pretty baffled as to what I have done wrong. I can confirm in the database that the passwords are actually hashing. I also read somewhere that passwords should be VARCHAR(50) in the database and this is the case with mine so it shouldn't be that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've read wrong, the default password hasher uses [**bcrypt**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (for now), which requires 60 chars, and may expand in the future in case the default algorithm changes. Stick with the maximum of 255 and you're on the safe side.

Comment: Is there a good way to change that without dropping users @ndm ?

Comment: The only thing that you need to "drop" are the passwords, they are broken. Just change the column length, then via CakePHP read all users, iterate over them, and save them with new passwords.

Answer (score 1):

So my passwords was too small, according to a helpful answer from ndm default password hasher needs varchar(60), the stuff I had read about varchar(50) could have been for blowfish which I don't use.

The syntax for easily changing the varcahr limit is: ALTER TABLE users CHANGE password password VARCHAR(255);

edit: I cannot mark my own answer as solved but the problem is solved.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after 48 hours. **http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer**

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not work right away, but is the form being POSTed?
You need to start debugging, change your function to this, to check:

```
public function login() 
    {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
        echo "YES, we have posted information!<br />"; var_dump($this->request);
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        echo "<br /><br />Let's have a look at $user = $this->Auth->identify();"; var_dump($this->request); 
            if($user){
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again.'));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to note those debugs down for if I get problems in the future! Ndm however allready correctly pointed out my problem and I answered my question with the solution.